# How to add Google Maps to website?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code I currently have for adding Google Maps to my website?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 simple questions:

1. How do I add in my API key to be used to make sure my server's IP isn't blocked?
2. This appears to be using logitude and latitude.  How can I change this to use the name of the city instead?  For example, so that "Houston" can be entered instead of the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

To add in a Google Map API key follow these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  Below is the line of code used to add your own key.  If the map does not show up it additional troubleshooting needs to be done (i.e. it may be blocked)

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(*YOUR KEY*)"></script>
```

The easiest way to add Houston to map center is too find the lat and long for Houston.  You could create form on page load which asks the user for their city, then geocodes the city and loads the map to the input location.  This would require quite a bit of additional work.